# Comments can't contain that content - "What have you tried?"

Tags: support, comments

"What have you tried?" - I've seen that comment a million times on question that ask for help (usually on really basic stuff) without showing any effort to solve it themselves. I've just wanted to post the same comment, but got a warning *Comments can't contain that content* instead.

This comment is asking for additional information from OP, which is what (I believe) comments are for.

What is the reason to ban this kind of comments?

Comment: [this is what one would better use instead of WHYT](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270919/839601)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[As stated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172912/161198) by [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9) on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com)

> comments consisting of little more than a raw link to whathaveyoutried.com are banned, and the threshold for deletion on comments like the one you use as an example has been lowered considerably: if you find them unhelpful and flag them, there's a good chance they'll be removed quickly.

In the same post, [and many others like it on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=what%20have%20you%20tried), you'll find plenty of discussions on the topic.

The comment is merely banned when it's just that comment. If you accompany it with a reasonable bit of further information, [it can still be part of a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147166/161198).

Comment: No real reasonable bit of further information is needed besides the fact of "What have you tried" is blunt and to the point and exactly that. I see no reason for it to be "banned" besides people whining about it. The only real thing I can see adding to the comment is, "What have you tried, we'd like to see so we can help debug" other than that I believe every new post should state what they've tried and what the haven't tried instead of wasting peoples time and doing what they have already tried :X

Comment: This answer doesn't really explain **why** such comments were banned.

Comment: See the linked content.

Comment: Linked answer by Shog still doesn't explain why this comment content is disallowed.

Comment: @TylerH I said "linked content". There is more than the first link to Shog's answer.

Comment: And I said "linked answer by Shog". Other links don't really offer an answer at all, just more discussion by the community, and an example comment.

Comment: Had this problem today. I simply asked the OP what they had tried, I do not see why it should be blocked!

Comment: @Bart "See the linked content" doesn't work for code answers, why does it work for meta answers? Isn't it a site policy to always include the relevant bit of linked content *in the answer*?

Comment: Are you saying my answer falls short there @Tyrsius? What is it missing?

Comment: Besides what @EasyBB mentioned, banning this comment is like to make SO a free service code. Sometimes even though the question has every bit of needed information it still lacks the user effort so they are just asking us to make what they coudn't even TRY !

Comment: How about banning questions that start with "How do I" at the same time?

Comment: What about `What have you tried so far?` Relevant question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41883763/how-do-i-get-max-date-from-these-sql-tables/41884155#41884155).

Comment: the error i got said, paraphrasing here, if they haven't shown what they tried why do you assume they have tried anything at all? well, my question is why should we assume they haven't? new users are often just bad at asking questions. what have you tried is also a way to make them realise they should try something first and maybe they will come back after that. i really think micromanaging what people post is ridiculous and as can be seen in this comment thread itself, easily bypassed by a slight change, unless you want to implement AI for something so trivial.

Comment: Asking "what have you tried?" is a great way to help train new users to make an attempt and show their work. It should not be banned and I can't fathom why anyone thinks banning it is helpful.

Comment: If you're asking literally just that, you're doing it wrong. If you want to know why it is banned, read through https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=what%20have%20you%20tried