# I cannot comment and get "Comments can´t contain that content"

Tags: support, comments

Currently I cannot comment on any question or answer on Stack Overflow. I receive:

> Comments can't contain that content

[image: Comments can't contain that content example]

Response is 500 (Internal Server Error)

```
POST http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25721780/comments 500 (Internal Server Error) 
jquery.min.js:4 send
jquery.min.js:4 f.extend.ajax
jquery.min.js:4 e.ajax
full.en.js?v=199f9091a7e7:3 r.extendPostUi.submitNewComment
full.en.js?v=199f9091a7e7:4 (anonymous function)
full.en.js?v=199f9091a7e7:4 (anonymous function)
full.en.js?v=199f9091a7e7:4 f.event.dispatch
jquery.min.js:3 h.handle.i
jquery.min.js:3 f.event.trigger
jquery.min.js:3 (anonymous function)
jquery.min.js:3 e.extend.each
jquery.min.js:2 e.fn.e.each
jquery.min.js:2 f.fn.extend.trigger
jquery.min.js:3 f.fn.(anonymous function)
jquery.min.js:3 (anonymous function)
full.en.js?v=199f9091a7e7:4 f.event.dispatch
jquery.min.js:3 h.handle.i
```

Comment: Perhaps a local network issue? I certainly don't have the same problem.

Comment: @MartijnPieters On any other side it ist working. But not on SO

Comment: See [“What have you tried” epidemic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172758/what-have-you-tried-epidemic) on the über-meta.

Comment: @Jehof: *Just* that comment? Or *any* comment?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yeah it is just that comment. think thats the case what Hamidi linked to.

Comment: The question is not unreasonable; not sure it deserves downvotes (although it is readily searchable)

Comment: That's not a bug, it's a feature. Please don't post useless comments. If you just post a plain "what have you tried", it's easy for the user to rationalize ignoring you. You should write a comment that states _why_ the user should include an attempt. This has the added benefit that instead of looking like a jerk yourself for posting an useless comment, you can make the OP feel like a jerk for not including any attempts, by explaining that the question feels like a code request or is unclear or possibly an xy problem or whatever else applies, and does thus not meet SOs quality standards.

Comment: @l4mpi thanks for you comment. yeah it seems to be a feature. A generic message that tells me that my content is not valid.

Comment: Usually, I comment something like this, instead: _"What have you tried? Have you done any research? As it is, this question is too broad, and will probably be closed as such. Try to search around a bit for possible solutions, try coding something, and come back for help (With a example of what you tried), if you can't get it to work. SO is not a site where you can just post a requirement and expect code in return."_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What have you tried?

as a comment is blocked on Stack Overflow because of [the issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172758/what-have-you-tried-epidemic) Frédéric Hamidi linked to.

In it's bald form it can be taken as rude, and there are better ways of asking the user for more information.

Comment: yes thats the case. A more descriptive message would be better I think

Comment: How much more descriptive than the current message do you want to have it? (not rude, just tell what's unclear)

Comment: @Jehof - the error is the same for if you try to enter any blocked content (there are several). It wouldn't make sense to have a specific error message for each item on the blocked list.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I don´t know. Maybe a link to the blocked content. Whats allowed and what not.

Comment: A generic message Content is not allowed, seems of for me. I wrote text into the comment field with a valid lenght. Next time I search before asking here.

Comment: @Jehof: maybe something like "That content is not allowed or not considered constructive."?

Comment: @PatrickHofman yeah that would be fine i think.

Comment: @Jehof: If you want to, feel free to create a feature request for it.

Comment: Is StackOverflow EU's Ban Scheme based?

Comment: Seems like the issue Frédéric Hamidi linked to would be better fixed by banning *repetition* of "What have you tried?" when it's already been put in a comment on the same question.

Answer (score 14):

This is a comment you need to use instead of [WHYT](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172760/165773):

> Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
>   it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
>   to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
>   and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
>   Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

The comment markdown for that is:

```
Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [ask].
```

<sub>Quoted from [Repository of useful pro-forma comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136615/165773).</sub>

Comment: thanks i will copy that to my clipboard. Hope that it does not gets blocked in the near future

Comment: when copying to clipboard, consider that "how to ask" there is actually a [magic link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/magic-links/info) - if you put `[ask]` into comment, system will automagically expand it into: [ask]

Comment: Better yet, ask *specific* questions of the asker that indicate you both read the question and understand the problem domain. If you don't have time to do that, you might consider whether you have time to leave a comment. You don't have to leave a comment when you downvote a poorly-asked or poorly-researched question.

Comment: @CodyGray ["Don't expect to make a difference if you just drop downvote and run away..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190413/165773)

Comment: I've read [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131029/ban-what-have-you-tried-links-in-comments/131031#131031) and I'm still puzzled by the aversion to simply asking, "what have you tried?" Particularly given the popularity of [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131031/159427). Dancing around the ban so we can get to our core question makes it seem like the ban is a bad idea.