# Removing comments that are no longer relevant (but were at the time of posting)

Tags: discussion, deleted-comments, comment-flags

Sometimes I miss something in an answer or I get something wrong. There comes a comment along the line:

> you missed this / You are wrong here

and my answer - if it is not immediately fixable - is:

> @user ty. You are right, I will edit

I think that this response is important as it shows that I know that the answer is currently wrong/incomplete and I am working on it.

However, after I make the edit I think those comments should be deleted as they hold no value now. I can easily remove my comment, but what about the original comment? I cannot expect that the comment-er will periodically check to see if I made the edit and he will delete the comment.

What should I do?

Should I just delete my comment?

Should I add a third comment letting him know I updated my answer, will delete my comments and ask him to delete his (he may take offense), wait a few minutes and then delete my comments?

Is the obsolete flag specially designed for this kinds of situation?

Or should I do nothing, and just leave it at that?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The *no longer needed* flag is designed for that kind of situation, yes. Flag such comments with *no longer needed*.

For a larger number of comments, flag your post with the *other* option and tell the moderator that all comments can be purged.

If, however, you can clear the comments in coordination with the other user, that'd always be preferable (as that saves the <del>janitors</del>moderators work). I sometimes use:

> Thanks! I've corrected that. This comment will self-destruct in 30.. 29.. 28..

then wait a while before deleting my comments. Usually the other party has picked up the hint.

---

At the time this answer was written, we still had an *obsolete* flag; the answer has since been edited to reflect the current flagging options.

Comment: I like that. I will steal it from you and use it as my own <evil laugth>!

Comment: I use something like "OK, lets clean up the comments now" and if it is a new (relative term) user I explain how to delete them as well. Usually works well. Usually. If nothing happens, I flag the comments or the posts. Usually.

Comment: Shame the system does not allow a "timeout" to be set when I post a comment.

Comment: @Ian, you can use [the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/delete-comment) and [write an app.](http://stackapps.com/) for that.

Comment: @TLama There is [already a query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/245986/search-for-short-comments?search=accept%20rate) you can run to find obsolete comments based on their content (ie the now-taboo "What have you tried?" comment)

Comment: @TylerH Why you say that that (no, not a spelling mistake) type of comment is a taboo?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel There was much meta discussion and some backend work by Shog to actually disallow that comment because it was becoming so automatic for people that they wouldn't even read the question before they commented; search "what have you tried not allowed" on MSO to read more.

Comment: @TylerH Thank you for explaining it. I've taken a quick look and, from what I understand, that type of comment is allowed if it has more content to explain itself and what is needed (or similar), based on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251309/comments-cant-contain-that-content-what-have-you-tried.

Comment: Note: you may end up with a declined flag if you do this incorrectly. I commented that I had fixed something after a user pointed out an issue in my answer. After leaving my comment up for awhile, I decided to mark the other user's comment as no longer needed. Then, because I can delete my own, I did. However, without my comment there anymore, theirs seemed to have had no response, and the "no longer needed" flag was declined. YMMV.

Comment: @JoshH: sounds like a human error case; I deleted the comment.

Comment: Martijn, both times I flagged obsolete comments plainly along the lines of, *"problem with X"*, followed by, *"thanks, X edited"*, the flags were declined. I don't want to waste the mod's time, so I feel compelled to ask: should we continue to flag these as suggested here, and just eat the declined flags that result from human error? Or raise a custom flag afterward? I don't want to cause problems with my account by accumulating declined flags, so I'm hesitant to continue flagging these. It feels like the system lost some useful context when they merged the "obsolete" option.

Comment: @CyRossignol: I would most definitely delete such comments. I'll take a look, looks like human error to me. Also, with 25 moderators, there may be some variability in handling.

Comment: @CyRossignol: I only see **one** declined comment flag on your main account. I'd say that was human error. Moderators handle *a lot of flags* every day (5k flags in the past week alone), so the occasional error does happen, it's inevitable. Sorry about that!

Comment: Thanks for checking, Martijn. I noticed that I only have one now as well, but I could have sworn this happened twice. It's been some time, though. Thanks for looking into it. I'll keep flagging these, then!