# Why a lot of comments instead of answers?

Tags: discussion

In a very large number of question, on Stack Overflow, a lot of users try to answer to the question using comments instead of placing an answer.

Of course, some of them are NOT clear as question, but users must be discourage from use comments instead of answers !

Why? To avoid downvoting? Is there a way to mitigate the use of the comments in my question?

Comment: Perhaps the *question* is at fault; if the question isn't clear people tend to put guesses in comments more often.

Comment: Maybe most of the questions are not clear at the time of posting?

Comment: Maybe most of the questions are lacking expected i/o

Comment: Maybe most of the questions are too broad

Comment: Maybe most of the questions states XY problem

Comment: I speak about TOO MANY situations. Of course, in some of them the question itself is not so clear, but NOT in all of them. I think there is an abuse of the comments

Comment: Well, in a serious note, answers cannot be posted until we are certain of few things. Think of a simple typo, which changes the entire meaning or representation of a code. (Note: now also you have a handful of comments, but not an answer. :-))

Comment: @SouravGhosh: can't you create an answer, include all of your comments into the answer and delete the comments... yes this is a situation where really 50 comments make difficult to find the answer.

Comment: See, frankly speaking, comments are comments and not meant to be answers. The questions which are _solved_ in comments can either be closed as typos, or any user can extract the answer from the comment and post that as an answer  making that as a CW. That's the way to go.

Comment: I'll chip in a comment when I'm offering an educated guess, not an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Answerers who only use comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments) or [Why answering in comments is trending?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272642/why-answering-in-comments-is-trending)

Comment: You are encouraged to [flag comments for removal](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281473/1497596) once they are no longer relevant.

Answer (score 18):

I tend to have high standard when answering questions. When I add an answer, I *try* to:

- Not answer a question that is a duplicate but close it instead. This means finding a duplicate, which is not always easy.
- Not answer questions that don't belong in Stack Overflow.
- Think about possible peripheral causes for the problem (e.g. Why can't I access the API? Maybe your network is down or your user is locked. Not interesting.)
- Test my code is actually working:

  - For the OP's sample data.
  - For other edge cases.
- Have a working example when applicable (e.g. fiddle).
- Quote and link official documentation when applicable.

So there are cases I'd comment instead of answer:

- When I vote to close it, but still want to help the OP with a specific answer.
- When I don't find the question interesting enough for a full answer.

Answer (score 7):

Roughly a [fifth of the questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/349501) only has comments:

```
Q but NC  | Q with C  | Q and A but no C   | Q and A with C
359,792   | 816,974   |   4,095,605        |   4,668,417
```

so I think we're doing fine.

Comments are used to get clarification about the question. If comments like that are needed it might be the first signal that the post has a quality issue. In some tags answers to low quality questions get down voted which might explain that users hold back on answering.

If your question requires a complicated or time-consuming answer users might first want to verify that they understood the issue well enough before they set to work.

If your own questions only receive comments and hardly answers, there might be an issue with your questions and not so much with the users that want to answer those.