# What should I do if my question invoked negative or off-topic comments?

Tags: discussion, questions

Should I delete that question and post again with fixes to prevent such comments? I think these comments are not helping at all, instead are just messing, but at the same time I feel guilty that the way I posed that question was what invoked them on first place, and now cannot clean them. If I edit the question the comments will still remain there and make even less sense yet, and they will keep messing with my question.

Should there exist an "off-topic" option, so that I can edit the question and then flag these comments as off-topic? Or just delete and post again?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*"Should I delete that question and post again with fixes to prevent such comments? "*

### No.

If the comments are genuinely bad, unconstructive or offensive, flag them.

Meanwhile, try to fix the question if that's what the comments are about.

Click on the flag next to the comment:

[image]

Then select a flag of your choice:

[image]

Comment: Related reading: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281473/removing-comments-that-are-no-longer-relevant-but-were-at-the-time-of-posting

Comment: More related reading: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307383/in-what-cases-can-the-offensive-flag-be-used