# How can we efficiently leave comments for editors?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, suggested-edits, comments

In a recent discussion about how to handle poor suggested edits, [Shog reminded us that it is possible to ping editors in comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/313553/465378) and pointed out that this is often a good way to try and halt sprees of poor edits. I thought this was novel advice, and [I gave it a shot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024722/determine-if-a-range-contains-a-value). Lo and behold, it worked! The message appears to have been received, and a moderator’s time was not required. Great, everything’s solved.

Wait.

What about [these comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ULCW.png)?

[image: picture of comment thread]

[Comments on Stack Exchange are ephemeral](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130990/188673), and comments unrelated to the post [aren’t sticking around](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281474/465378). But this introduces a quandary: how do I deal with creating these meta-comments? These are now wholly useless! They don’t add any value at all to the post because these comments serve as *messages to a **user***, not any sort of commentary on the post. The post author doesn’t care, and future visitors certainly don’t.

So now I have just one option: delete my comment and flag the other comment (the reply by the editor) for deletion. But wait! Now I’ve completely invalidated the whole point of doing this! Now a moderator needs to intervene to clean up our useless comments. Darn.

This is pretty sucky because in my attempt to solve one problem, I created three:

1. A moderator’s attention is required to clean up the comment conversation.
2. The original poster got needlessly notified of this conversation, which should really be out of band.
3. There’s no way for me to follow up on that conversation because I would just be adding to the problem, even though I’d really like to respond to the editor’s comment to continue to clarify things.

Hmm... this sounds like a job for *Stack Overflow Chat!* Ah, but blast: [one cannot start a conversation with arbitrary users in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57538/188673). No direct communication for me.

I thought it was a good idea, and I felt accomplished at first, but in retrospect, perhaps I should have just raised a flag to begin with. After all, [moderators have the tools to deal with this sort of thing](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/), and I do not. I’m just a lowly user, after all.

But no, that is not [the mission of Stack Overflow](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/membership-has-its-privileges/) at all, is it? Built by the community and moderated by the community. I may not be a moderator, but the capability to help shape the site—if only a little—is one of the reasons I participate here, and [clearly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/313553/465378), this is a case where that is encouraged. Is leaving a comment worth it? What can I do once those comments have had the desired effect? And finally, is it possible to do all of this without burdening diamond moderators?

Comment: Perhaps you could edit in the examples as _quoted text_, seeing as the links to comments are now all broken thanks to the deft hand of your answering moderators...

Comment: Yeah, quote or screenshot next time please.

Comment: I’ve edited in a screenshot of the comments for posterity. I originally didn’t want to call to much attention to the user in question, but I *think* it’s okay—the behavior in question is good.

Comment: I know space is limited but it would be nice to mention why to wait till 2k rep cause just now it just comes across as an arbitrary elitist number. I presume once 2k is hit edits don't need reviewed?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I should note that it's way easier for moderators to delete obsolete comments once a problem has been resolved than to deal with a flag about a problematic editor.

It can take us just a few seconds to clean up obsolete comment flags. For a flag on the reviewer themselves, we have to pull up their review history, read through a bunch of reviews, decide which action to take, and then edit ban, draft up a message, or decline the flag if we find the evidence lacking. Sometimes these custom flags can hang around for a while if they don't catch our eye, so an editor can continue on unaware in the meanwhile.

You still have the problems of notifying a third party in your comments, but a comment to an editor usually saves moderators work overall. I wouldn't consider these a burden, since we can remove them quickly and they can often get the job done faster than a flag.

Answer (score 21):

I don't particularly worry about these. When you consider the vast quantity of "meta" comments left on answers and *especially* on questions, notes to the editors are little more than a drop in the ocean, a tiny bit of extra noise mixed into the whelming flood of "what have you tried?" and "can you explain what you meant by 'it doesn't work?'" comments.

They would also be trivial to identify and clean up automatically, should anyone ever decide to do so.

[As Brad notes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313568/how-can-we-efficiently-leave-comments-for-editors/313607#313607), the work required for moderators is trivial, should you take it upon yourself to flag these. And if they *work*, then the reduction in noise from bad edits more than compensates for that added by a few extra comments.

Comment: I think the issue exposes a much deeper problem: That flaggers and reviewers have absolutely no communication with each other (except if it is the mod reviewing the flag). Worse (at least in my opinion), is that reviewers cannot communicate together either, or even leave a note. I've seen a not-insignificant amount of edits where I've picked reject as the edit appears to be correct, but is actually detrimental - and it's likely a reviewer unfamiliar with the tag would not notice it. And yet, there's no way to leave a note to other reviewers that the edit should be rejected (and why).

Comment: Anyone can flag a `what have you tried` comment and it will be instantly removed though `:)`