# How can I leave a note to some user?

Tags: support

Well, probably this has been asked and answered a bazillion times, if so, just mark it as duplicate so I can see the answer.

Q: How can I leave a note to some user?

Edit (add context): a question of mine has been edited, the edit was (rightfully) rejected be someone else. The edit tried to be helpful (but wasn't: the opposite of good is good intentions, they say).

I want to "sync" with the one who suggested the edit.

(Just as a current example.)

Edit 2: someone else has an avatar that scales down perfectly. Most avatars look right if seen in full format, but sh***y if scaled down. I would like to ask the user how this was accomplished, (because I have tried to scale down some pictures to thumbnail size and I could just as well have taken a picture of a squashed fly).

Comment: In what context? You can leave a comment under one of their posts, if your note is about the post.

Comment: @Laurel, possibly, but my intention is to specifically(privately) contact a user. I don't care if this can be retrieved by others, but I don't want to post it visibly to those who wouldn't care and regard it as spam if posted in a comment.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313568/how-can-we-efficiently-leave-comments-for-editors?rq=1

Comment: @Laurel, not quite what I'm looking for, comments are seen by others and add noise if not aimed to the Q/A.

Comment: *"someone else has an avatar that scales down perfectly. Most avatars look right if seen in full format, but sh\*\*\*y if scaled down. I would like to ask the user how this was accomplished"* ... that seems like a question to ask on a Meta site. But other than the user leaving contact information in their profile, there is no way to privately contact them.

Comment: Maybe try [Should we be able to send private messages to other users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261885/should-we-be-able-to-send-private-messages-to-other-users) It's a (declined) feature request for what you're looking for, which should tell you we don't have that particular feature.

Comment: @Bart it looks like you are the only-one sane out there.5 down-votes are enough, no matter if I'm too stupid to pose the question right or if nearly erveryone else ... !!!stop here!!! .. I'm going to delete this question.

Comment: Can't delete it, there's an answer now, and one that understands the question.

Comment: I wouldn't accuse me of any form of sanity. ;) But don't worry too much about the downvotes. Meta is a bit different than regular sites in that respect. Some of them may simply indicate that "we" really dislike such a feature or being privately contacted. Meta votes won't buy you anything anyway. Btw, you can't delete the question because it has an upvoted answer now. But it will do no harm.

Comment: @Bart, unluckily, no. Down-vote-tornados are a known form of social behavior, all over the place and down to the material world. But I get your message :-)

Comment: It was not so much the proposed duplicate that solved my question but the accepted answer here, but to avoid discussion overhead, I accept the proposed duplicate, for simplicity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to their profile and see if they've posted contact information there. If they have, they don't mind being contacted. If they haven't, they don't want to be reached off-site so we should respect their privacy.

Comment: So, in other words, there is, intentionally, no way to contact a user privately using stack*-pseudonym. If I got that right, this is the answer for my question. I *would* have liked a way to contact username to username, but then, this is not a chat-room, so this OK.

Comment: @GyroGearloose Yes, that is 100% correct. In order to protect the sanity of the site's top users, there's intentionally no way to contact them privately/directly. ;)

Comment: @GyroGearloose Note that it's generally better to just post your question to the entire site where it is on-topic anyway. Scale is the biggest advantage to using Stack Overflow.