# Is it okay to downvote questions asking if some code could work but not actually trying it?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, comments, downvotes

Should we downvote questions asking if a specific feature the OP wants to try works, when the OP hasn't tried the posted code?

I sometimes see questions where the OP is posting some snippet of code and asking whether it would work or not. [I am aware of "*What have you tried?*" comments which aren't allowed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251309/comments-cant-contain-that-content-what-have-you-tried). This situation is slightly different: the OP is not asking **how** something he wants to accomplish can be done. I'm referring to questions where the OP is asking **can** something he wants to try actually work?

I feel that someone who is asking if some feature can work hasn't done the minimal requirement before asking. That is to say, trying the code and reporting any error to point us in the right direction. An OP who is actually asking about an error that cannot be understood would do exactly this.

In consequence, should we downvote such questions? Can we leave comments such as "*Have you actually tried what you are asking for?*" or "*What's the error if you try the code?*" Can there be a flag for this kind of question?

Feel free to ask me for the link to the question if needed.

Comment: Thanks but I still think this was worth asking about it in meta.

Comment: Are you referring to questions where the OP says e.g. *"I want to foo the bar. I was thinking of doing something like: `...code...`. Would this work?"*, rather than just trying it and finding out themselves?

Comment: This kind of questions exactly. Finding out themselves and posting the error if any.

Comment: Then yes, I think a downvote and commenting e.g. *"Have you tried it? What happened?"* would be appropriate in many cases.

Comment: I have trouble parsing your question, especially the title. Could you clarify that? If  English grammar is a problem, it might be better to use shorter sentences.

Comment: I edited the title. Sorry, English is not my native language.

Comment: I just downvote.  It's bad enough when posters have not done any debugging, never mind when they could not even be bothered to build/test.  IMHO, all such questions are just noise, disguised 'check/fix the homework I copied' and the like.

Comment: I think, if the try out can be accomplished in a couple of minutes, downvote, if it's more complex, no downvote. But it also depends on the user's experience. Simple things can get complicated :-)

Comment: Can you link to example questions? I'm sure you have something horrible in mind. But it can be valid to ask "Does this idea of mine even have a chance of working?". If well asked these can be very interesting questions. For example "Can a TCP server based on threads potentially serve 100k connections? Is this viable?". (Answer: "no, because...")

Comment: @usr [This is the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29444609/store-operator-as-variable)

Comment: @D4V1D you should make clear in your question that you are talking about junk questions. You are pretty much asking "Can I close this crap under the current rules?". We are not talking about hidden jewels here.

Comment: We surely are not talking about hidden jewels. But I wanted to know what behaviour to adopt in such case.

Comment: I feel like the "did you try it" response such questions get promotes the misconception that if code worked when you tried it, the code is correct. This is absolutely not something we should be teaching people.

Comment: @user2357112 it depends on the nature of the question. Questions on matters of syntax such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29218892/73226) could certainly have been answered by trying it others not as observing behaviour in one set of circumstances might not mean it is valid to infer that this is guaranteed in all circumstances.

Comment: @user2357112: Well, it's certainly a problem when people think "it worked, for me, this time" is the same as "it's correct". But then the question should be whether it's guaranteed to always produce the correct result, with test-cases and the like, not whether it could work *at all*.

Comment: With git, confirmation that your "delete several branch refspecs based on some criteria" code works the way you want it to can be _critical_ to make sure it works before running it. With some other questions, maybe the consequence of getting it wrong the first time is lower.

Comment: Why is this a topic in first place? You care more about how to legally down vote questions, rather than try to help people and guide them how to ask it in a better form next time? Weird.

Comment: Sometimes, the OP helpfully includes the code in the question.  You get a 20 line program, with "will this work" underneath.  I'll always downvote those, although my comment depends on how facetious I feel.

Comment: Your votes are your own. As long as you are not committing vote fraud with them, you are the sole arbiter of how and when you use them.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Yes, if the asker is using SO as a human compiler, downvoting and closing with extreme prejudice is called for.

Probably with the debug-reason, because he did not say what the error was.
Or with the unclear reason, because we are charitable and think he has an actual question he simply could not express.

Because some seem to mis-read my answer: I'm not even hinting that testing is enough to guarantee correctness, only that doing a simple test-run is obviously part of the "minimum research effort" absolutely required for there being any possibility of the question being anything but a waste of time for everyone (*including asker*), if doing so is at all feasible.

Comment: But .. but .. the StackOverflow human compiler features natural language processing!

Comment: @VatsalManot: It does throw `question closed` errors though if you don't use grammar properly.

Comment: This answer betrays hostility and a lack of imagination! See my answer.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit: Added a paragraph to make it obvious that's not the case.

Comment: This answer is still wrong, and if you don't know why, no explanation will help you.

Comment: @Jase How about writing your own answer then instead of making pointless rant comments? As probably most other users here I see no problem in refusing to compile code for lazy people etc. If someone has problems with this part, he/she can´t write any program, so he/she should learn it now instead of asking other people everytime.

Comment: I've always assumed that part of the SO infrastructure involved computers, rather than being an entirely made of humans.  How much does an HTTP server get paid these days?

Answer (score 22):

To add to the other answers, note that simply compiling a piece of code is often not sufficient to determine whether it is correct and, by extension, whether it will "work" *reliably* and *repeatably*.

So, before you downvote and vote-to-close, be sure that you understand what the OP is *really* asking. Are they asking you whether the code will compile? Or are they asking you whether the code is strictly valid and well-defined? In languages such as C++ there is a wide gulf between the two, and the latter question is completely on-topic and appropriate here.

Comment: There are plenty of times where I see questions that barely more than "will something like this work?" followed by a chunk of code.  In those instances the "unclear or not useful" part of the downvote description applies.

Comment: +1 This is especially true where any kind of concurrency is involved. In cases like that, it seems perfectly reasonable for a user to ask if something will work in order to make sure they're not overlooking something important.

Comment: This should be a comment, because it doesn't actually give the conclusion, only some thoughts about it.  The correct conclusion is that "Is (chunk of code) valid and well-defined?" is off-topic, while "I wrote (chunk of code) and tested it (according to plan).  It passed all my testing.  Is it guaranteed to work by the language, or did I just get lucky with undefined-behavior producing the results I was looking for?" is on-topic.

Comment: @BenVoigt: The final sentence constitutes a conclusion. Whether that conclusion is "correct" or not according to you does not determine whether this post is an answer.

Comment: Ahh, it wasn't clear that you actually intended to say that "Here is (code).  I haven't tried compiling or executing it myself.  Is it strictly valid and well-defined?" is on-topic.  I'm going to have to amicably disagree.

Comment: Imo this is the best answer, "work" can mean a lot of things other than just compile, the user should be asked to clarify what they mean.

Comment: This answer doesn't actually address the question as asked. The question stipulates that the person posting the question is asking whether code will work without having tried to make it work. Whether they are asking about whether it will compile or whether it will do as intended, without their having tried it for themselves, they don't even know whether there's a question ask. It's not on-topic to ask whether something will work if it  does work but you don't know that because you haven't bothered to check for yourself.

Answer (score 14):

Yes. Trying out one's own code is the absolute minimum of **research effort**<sup>1</sup>. Lacking that, downvoting the question is exactly the appropriate<sup>2</sup> action to take.

<sub>1) Except when the question asks about the compilation itself of course, e.g. for archaic languages

2) It's even in the tooltip of the downvote button!</sub>

Answer (score 3):

If it is evident that no effort has gone into looking for a solution, then downvoting the question is appropriate - it sends an important message to the user and to the community.  SO is intended to *help* people who have an problem and then share this problem with the community.  It is not supposed to be a place where people post work to be done, because they lack the knowledge or time to invest in even attempting to find a solution.

However, in some cases this is not clear cut - the user may not have phrased the question well or has more relevant information which could have been added to the post.  If this appears to be the case, then the community can help to develop the question, before assessing whether it is worthy of an answer.

Answer (score -10):

People come to Stack Overflow for help. You can help them if you want to or ignore the question if you don't. There's no reason to downvote.

Comment: If an answer don't answer, it should be downvote and flag as not an answer. Personnally I also add a comment scuh as *"Please, ask you own question instead of posting an answer"*

Comment: You misapprehend the purpose of Stack Overflow. People may come to Stack Overflow for help, but the purpose of Stack Overflow is to capture high quality answers to high quality questions about practical programming problems. People may get helped by those questions and answers, but that is not the express purpose of Stack Overflow, historically.

Comment: Nah, there's lots of reasons to downvote. "Does not show any research effort" is even explicitly called out as a reason on the downvote tooltip.

Comment: It got edited, I said there was no reason to be a jerk. Some people on this platform are very toxic and unhelpful. I still can't comprehend why someone would take time out of their day to be facetious to a person asking for help. Some people are just learning how to code and they don't know the jargon or they just need help with a hypothetical scenario. If you're expending effort to help them, recognize that they are a fellow human and try to empathize with their situation.

Comment: Ok then, please show us an example of someone on this platform being very toxic and unhelpful. We would like to understand what happened.

Comment: can't add screenshots here but this thread is a great example. Just try to be empathetic and understanding of others. it's chaos, be kind.

Comment: @Edward I arrive a bit late (I was not notified of your comment), but that assessment does not seem fair. The comments in this answer were explaining the aims of the platform and the purpose of voting. They stand as constructive criticism, far from chaotic. What it seems to have happened here was a clash of expectations from users when asking and answering questions, as it often happens here, but it is unreasonable to expect a customer treatment and equate the occurrence of anything less as toxic.

Answer (score -11):

Sometimes the OP just have a slight idea of what he needs to do and asking without code, or pieces of it may be appropriate.  The question is what matters.

Comment: If you have a programming question, then you should have a small piece of code where this problem lies. If your question is about design, you should have a small sample of the design you have now. Even if your question is about *how do I foo the bar?*, then you should have an idea how *to foo*, because that's a concise question that may have a concise answer.

Comment: The code is what matters!