# Has the "What have you tried?" comment policy changed?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I flagged [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31147330/convert-numbers-to-date#comment-50305009) yesterday, which I expected to be deleted with [a single flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172758/what-have-you-tried-epidemic/172760#172760). My action did not remove the comment and my flag was declined.

The comment was not accompanied by a [reasonable bit of further information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251309/comments-cant-contain-that-content-what-have-you-tried/251310#251310), so I'm confused.

Has the policy on these comments changed?

EDIT:
Just to be clear, I'm aware that there are far more important issues for moderators to handle. My goal in asking this question is to find clarification. I don't want to create more work for mods by flagging comments (or anything else for that matter) if there isn't a need for it.

Comment: Well mods are busy.  And while that _might_ have been a helpful flag, there are many more important things for them to deal with than those kinds of comments.

Comment: There certainly are more important things. Which is why I don't want to create unnecessary work for them if the policy has changed. I'm just looking for clarification; this shouldn't be read as a complaint.

Comment: The "single flag" not working, if that hasn't been removed, may be because the comment was worded in a way that the filter does not pick up on.

Comment: Re the *"Can you show what you've tried?"* comment, that was a case where it was helpful comment. The OP had posted nothing at all, not even a verbal description of the code - anything would be better, not just a full MCVE. Please explain what sort of "reasonable bit of further information" would you expect in that  specific case?

Comment: @smci Literally anything. A link to [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or even a brief comment on *why* "what have you tried" would have been beneficial. Considering the low reputation and poor quality question, its reasonable to assume OP wasn't aware of any of this. A simple "If we can see what you've already tried, we may be better able to assist" would have been a reasonable bit of further information IMHO.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I declined to delete this comment, because that question illustrates where such a comment is actually correctly used. The question was giving a specification and no indication as to where they were stuck.

Quoting Shog from the very post you linked to in the comments there:

> Just to clarify: I don't begrudge comments asking for clarification or explanation *when they're applicable* - I think George made it clear in the OP that these are not *inherently* bad.

and

> If you don't have the time or inclination to engage in conversation with the author of a post, don't comment - just vote.

The commenter *was* engaging in conversation there.

Comment: Okay, that's good to know. I hadn't heard of the policy before this, and I definitely see where it could be abused, but this seemed like a valid case where OP had nothing for us to go on. In the future, would it be better to change my wording/link to MCVE?

Comment: @MorganThrapp Linking to MCVE when the OP should add one is _always_ a good idea, so long as you do so politely and constructively.

Comment: @MorganThrapp: I generally try to explain that we have no starting point to help out without a MCVE; linking to that help page is certainly going the extra mile.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I read the post I linked to and did not feel the comment was `asking for clarification or explanation`. Because the question was so lacking, there was no content to explain. I viewed the comment as nothing more than noise. A link to MCVE, or an explanation of what should be included would have been better, and because that was not supplied, I saw the commenter was *not* inclined to engage in conversation. I do however understand your reasoning. Perhaps this is simply a difference in opinion. I'll be more thorough in the future.

Comment: Alright, I'll keep that in mind for the future! Speaking of the help page, where would I find it?

Comment: @MorganThrapp: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve