# Flag suggestion: "Did you even tried?"

Tags: discussion, flags

I am "new" user on SO but in fact I've been using this page for many years.

Lately I feel like the question quality has greatly dropped (I bet that everyone noticed it).

There are plenty examples of "give a hint of doing this" or "I want to do X tell me how" -> [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38926908/rotate-enemys-head-in-unity) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27200801/how-to-jump-and-fall-in-unity/27206692#27206692) (those are just examples)

I don't want to make the moderator's life harder with new flags and longer queues. But this approach annoys me. The programmers/engineers have to have critical thinking and problem solving skills.

So, I am suggesting a new flag of "Please give the steps you followed or reword the question"

This may be a duplicate of these two threads: [first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308604/shouldnt-there-be-an-option-to-close-a-question-if-they-are-college-related) and [second](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298425/has-the-what-have-you-tried-comment-policy-changed)

Thanks.

Comment: What would your flag do? As described, it would be completely worthless because all you are doing is flagging to say "this person didn't try anything". You can do that with downvoting. Here's a hint, mods are humans with limitations, not magical all knowing beings who are experts every programming language

Comment: Deleted my comment, as I agree with the pertinent point made by @psubsee2003 above

Comment: I don't even think that "trying anything" is a required for a good question. Very simplified, the basic formula that defines a good question − assuming that the standard on-topic criteria are met − is complexity + interestingness + effort. If "interestingness" is very high but effort is low then that might be perfectly okay. "Effort" is only really needed for low-complexity and low-interesting questions (usually "this code has a bug please help"-sort of questions). Again, this is very much simplified and much more can be said about this, but the point is: "effort" is *not* a necessity.

Comment: Just to expand on my initial comment a bit..... "can we have a flag to do `x`" is a very common request.  But no one who proposes such a flag ever thinks about what that flag is supposed to accomplish.  In this case, essentially you are saying "I am to lazy to do anything but pass the buck to someone else to fix".  There are tools to deal with these posts already.  You can flag/vote-to-close or downvote or edit the post or comment.  So involving a moderator doesn't do anything you can't already do on your own.  And as @Carpetsmoker said lack of effort doesn't mean bad question automatically

Comment: "Lately I feel like the question quality has greatly dropped..." -member for 4 months. ;)

Comment: "Lately I feel like the question quality has greatly dropped..." From 2014: [Question quality is dropping on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252506)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Downvote does exactly that: "this question does not show any research effort" in existing and clearly specified way.

It is very unclear why adding second mechanism for the same thing would be beneficial for the site.