# "What have you tried" vs. new Code of Conduct

Tags: discussion, feature-request, code-of-conduct, specific-comment

[Comments can't contain that content - "What have you tried?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251309/comments-cant-contain-that-content-what-have-you-tried) seems to not be the case (or the comment on [How to change the logic for the last element while mapping an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52009343/438992) is far enough off?!) and I'm wondering how just that content jibes with the new CoC.

I don't find the comment "rude" or a breach of social etiquette, but I *do* find it sub-optimal given the new CoC. IIRC there are some canonical links for most of the items listed on the "Beginner's Asking Questions" page (the link escapes me) but it might be easier to be ettiquettier if they were more trivially available either via flags or in comments.

Comment: there's already a close reason for questions that don't contain enough code/information to be answered. If it doesn't require code to be answered, asking what have you tried wouldn't be useful anyway.

Comment: Is this asking why that specific comment was allowed (probably the "so far"), or is this asking for better heuristics to block similar trite comments from being posted, or something else?

Comment: "What have you researched / tried so far?" is, IMO, one of the BEST ways of prompting the OP to re-think how they are asking their question. Once they respond to that comment, then they can be guided into editing their question into something valuable.

Comment: @Olly most of the times that I can remember anyone actually responding to "what have you tried" at all, the response has been some version of "I don't even know where to start". Have you observed something different than that, or do you think that's a good starting point for improving the question?

Comment: I've seen it act as a prompt for: "Well, I tried `x`, and got `y message`...", which then leads nicely into: "edit your question to include that information..." and on we go.

Comment: @BoltClock Honestly I'm not sure. I *think* I want magic comments to link to relevant FAQ/CoC/Meta posts: "What have you tried?" is *accurate*, but not *instructional*, and somewhat brusque. I *like* the new CoC (as hard as it is for me to be nice) but would prefer easier routes to support new users.

Answer (score 14):

I don't think anything has changed as a result of the new CoC. The new CoC just rewords what is already being implemented.

I personally prefer more direct phrasing:

> Please show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck.

The assumption that one expects there to have been *multiple* attempts, when in fact there have been none, may be a more chilling revelation to OP.

The problem with `What you have tried?` is you often get some vague or ambiguous description. Which may make matters worse.

Comment: Hm I like this wording better (although I'd modify it to "attempt(s)". I guess I'll just write up some macros 'cuz it looks like this (very vague) proposal will go nowhere. But I may incorporate something very close to this.

Answer (score -12):

The best "what have you tried" comment is a downvote. This was true before the CoC and remains true.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I tend to disagree--I'd rather help the person understand than punish them. People that are new here I are like kids: they don't know the rules, the social norms, etc: you don't punish a kid for doing something they don't know is wrong, you teach them. *Repeated* abuse, punishment, just like kids.

Comment: A downvote doesn't communicate "What have you tried?" It communicates one or more of a *multitude* of things that is left up to the author to guess. There's no guarantee it'd even *occur* to the author that that is one of the things being communicated.

Comment: @BoltClock Yes, that.

Comment: @DaveNewton Although it's true that it doesn't convey the same thing as a comment, a downvote isn't a punishment either. It hints everyone else that the question is in need of improvements before it's answered.

Comment: @E_net4 Without context it's pointless to downvote if your goal is to help the poster. In general, mine is; YMMV. If it's *accompanied* by what I'm talking about, fine, but I still don't see the point in piling downvotes on someone who either doesn't know what they're doing it doesn't know how to ask what they mean. (Noting that this is specifically targeted at new users, not serial idiots.)

Comment: @DaveNewton Granted, the purpose of downvotes is not to help the poster, but to help _everyone else_. Visitors will understand that there are issues in the content, and answerers may choose to tackle other questions. I don't understand what you mean with "serial idiots", though. :(

Comment: @E_net4 Not everybody bothers learning how to ask questions: they *should* be punished. I may be the odd man out, but I'd rather broaden our reach and user base, and IMO downvoting newbs doesn't help ¯\_(ツ)_/¯